# LKM: Last block written to device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to find a way, inside a module, to keep track of the last block written to a block device.  The specific device I need is the one mounted at root (I know the /dev/ name ahead of time if that helps.)

My original idea was to wrap the submit_bio function, since it has a logging function already if you "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump".  Unfortunately it seems I'd need to modify the source code to make that function a pointer.  I'd like to keep this all inside the module if at all possible.

After that, I looked into finding the file system type, and wrapping the default file operations (these are already function pointers, after all).  Those are declared as a const, though, so same issue.

This is kind of an odd thing to be trying to do, I understand.  Need to do it none-the-less.    Does anyone have any ideas that might get me going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel provides several different tracing toolkits; the [`blktrace` tools](http://brick.kernel.dk/snaps/) were designed specifically for block devices. The `blkparse(1)` tool will parse the output of the `blktrace(8)` utility. (At least Ubuntu has these packaged in the `blktrace` package; I expect other distributions to be similar.) The `bklparse(1)` tool can give you the sector information.

`Documentation/trace/events.txt` describes another tracing mechanism -- one that could allow you to follow the `block:block_bio_complete` event, which includes the sector information. This won't require installing the `bkltrace` toolkit but I'll (sheepishly) admit that I don't know where to *read* the trace log.