# how can I monitor Linux file access per file realtime

Tags: linux, file, monitoring

I'm trying to identify, which files are accessed realtime and check the speed of read and write on it. Something like an lsof, showing realtime file access speed per file (iostat per file).
(In Windows this is the Resource Monitor's disk table.)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm using XFS as filesystem, if that counts.

Comment: [I wrote an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10038275/377270) that I _hope_ provides you with useful links to start researching. (I don't know any mechanism to solve this specific question right away...)

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at LoggedFS. It provides very nice output WHAT happens with WHICH files in realtime.

http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/

It should be available in your distro's Package Manager (apt-get install loggedfs) and can be easily invoked without need of configuration:

```
loggedfs -f /home
```

Comment: For me (Ubuntu server 12.04.3 LTS amd64 on ext4 fs) `loggedfs` simply breaks / stops all filesystem access to files below the given mountpoint except for `root` myself, throwing errors instead of actual  filesystem messages. I don't downvote this, though, as this might just be a problem on this particular system.